# Where/how to install Drush when running multiple versions of Drupal

Tags: drush

I use a Mac for Drupal development and am a long time user of Drush.

Getting ready to develop a new Drupal 8 site and installed via "Option A" as described https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-composer-to-manage-drupal-site-dependencies

Following those instructions "out of the box", I wind up with a Drush 9.x instance inside of the Drupal 8 repository.

It is my understanding that Drush 9 won't support Drupal 7.  So, I'm forced to have multiple versions of Drush unless I run one global instance of Drush 8.x.  At least so it seems to me.

I'm also trying to make the shift to composer and installed Drush 8 as documented  [here.](http://docs.drush.org/en/8.x/install-alternative/)

And sadly, that instance breaks unless I list the mysql host as "127.0.0.1" (instead of localhost).  And if I do that, Drupal breaks.

So - first question: 1) What is are the recommendations for Drush installation on a Mac running multiple versions of Drupal. Is it preferred to run on global instance? (Drush 8.x) - or leverage composer to install Drush locally within each Drupal instance.

2) Why (maybe out of the scope of this discussion) do I suddenly get an error installing Drush 8 using composer on my Drupal 7 instance?   Drupal 8 fails as well, but a different error.

Comment: You can add Drush using composer `composer require drush/drush`. Then you can install the Drush Launcher, which will call the local drush in whatever project you are working on.

Comment: Thank you for the idea. I believe this is the code you're referring to (https://github.com/drush-ops/drush-launcher). Actually - I tried that but will look more closely at that option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run Drush 8 and Drush 9 at the same time.

### Drush 8

Install Drush 8 globally:

```
# Browse to https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/releases and download the drush.phar attached to the latest 8.x release.

# Test your install.
php drush.phar core-status

# Rename to `drush` instead of `php drush.phar`. Destination can be anywhere on $PATH. 
chmod +x drush.phar
sudo mv drush.phar /usr/local/bin/drush

# Optional. Enrich the bash startup file with completion and aliases.
drush init
```

Reference http://docs.drush.org/en/8.x/install/

### Drush 9

Use a composer based Drupal 8 scaffold which contains Drush 9:

```
composer create-project drupal-composer/drupal-project:8.x-dev some-dir --stability dev --no-interaction
```

Reference https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-composer-to-manage-drupal-site-dependencies

### Running Drush

You don't need a launcher to run `drush`, because the global Drush 8 acts as one if it finds a locally installed Drush. So you can install a different Drush version for each Drupal site and have always Drush 8 as fallback globally. But I wouldn't recommend to install Drush 8 locally, in my experience the current Drush 8 works downloaded as phar file the most reliable. Ignore all older instructions how to install Drush by composer.

BTW if you still have a non composer based Drupal 8 site, the global Drush 8 works for Drupal versions > 8.3 as well, despite that it's not officially listed in the compatibility list. And you need Drush 8 to manage a Drupal 8 site without composer, because in Drush 9 the tools to manage Drupal without composer have been removed.

Comment: I'm marking this as answered. Although it really didn't address the question about the relevance of being forward compatible (e.g., installing/maintaining DRUSH with COMPOSER).   completely purged all instances and reference for and to the old DRUSH and reinstalled 8 per above. Didn't work. Then; configured per http://docs.drush.org/en/7.x/configure/.  These are V7 instructions and should be included for V8.  That got things working. Then, I installed Drupal 8 per https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project.  Both Drush 8.x and 9.x are working.