# Having multiple Drush instances for different core versions

Tags: drush

So in my environment, I have some websites on Drupal 7 and some on Drupal 8, and since the latest Drush 9 works with Drupal 8.4+ I was wondering if there's a way to be able to have both Drush 9 and (put another version here) to work on both major Drupal versions.

I'd like to be able to just use `drush` as my main alias and not define different aliases for different Drupal versions.

Comment: instead of using one global drush you can install drush via composer for each website in a verison you want so it would be scoped only to that particular website.

Comment: Or just install Drush 8 globally and Drush 9 local to each project. It will automatically use the correct one when in a project folder.

Comment: So there's no way to have them both installed globally? considering I rather skip fooling around with composer in general

Comment: Yeah you can install them both globally, but it's totally up to you how you manage that. You could create aliases, for example (`drush8 cc all`, `drush9 cr`, etc), or take any number of other approaches. Using project-specific versions is recommended, though

Comment: The documentation for Drush suggest not to globally install it, if I recall correctly. It is even not supported anymore.

Comment: Today it's drush tomorrow it can be anything. To manage different project's dependencies efficiently developers use tools like https://www.drupalvm.com/

Comment: [It is recommended that Drupal 8 sites be built using Composer, with Drush listed as a dependency.](http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/)

Comment: It is recommend to install Drush 8 globally (downloaded as phar file, not via composer, see http://docs.drush.org/en/8.x/install) and Drush 9 locally (preferable included already in the composer project), see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/263423/where-how-to-install-drush-when-running-multiple-versions-of-drupal/263439#263439.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ideal way would be to use Composer to set up your projects. I'd recommend [Composer templates for Drupal projects](https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project). Then add Drush to your project: `composer require drush/drush`.

Now install [Drush Launcher](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush-launcher) on your machine, globally. Drush Launcher provides a `drush` command that always finds and uses the locally installed Drush from the `/vendor` folder.

```
$ cd MYDRUPAL
$ drush --version
Drush Launcher Version: 0.6.0
Drush Commandline Tool 9.3.0
```

---

But probably you can not simply rebuild your projects. Then you may want to install two different global Drush versions. See https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/releases for all available versions.

#### `drush8`

```
$ sudo git clone https://github.com/drush-ops/drush.git /usr/local/src/drush8

$ cd /usr/local/src/drush8

# Check the latest Drush 8 version at https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/releases
$ sudo git checkout 8.4.10

# Linux:
$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/src/drush8/drush /usr/bin/drush8

# Mac:
$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/src/drush8/drush /usr/local/bin/drush8

$ sudo composer install

$ drush8 --version
Drush Version   :  8.4.10
```

#### `drush9`

```
$ sudo git clone https://github.com/drush-ops/drush.git /usr/local/src/drush9

$ cd /usr/local/src/drush9

# Check the latest Drush 9 version at https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/releases
$ sudo git checkout 9.3.0

# Linux:
$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/src/drush9/drush /usr/bin/drush9

# Mac:
$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/src/drush9/drush /usr/local/bin/drush9

$ sudo composer install

$ drush9 --version
Drush Version   :  9.3.0
```

Source: [Installing & Using Drupal Drush on Debian 7](https://linode.com/docs/websites/cms/drush-drupal/) (Bookmark this!)

Answer (score 4):

I do a slightly different method than @leymannx outlined.

I have Drush 8 installed globally.  In my case, I have a git clone and I periodically fetch and checkout one of the 8.x.y tags.  This is on my bash $PATH.  This is what I use to manage my Drupal 7 sites.

All of my Drupal 8 sites use [drupal-composer/drupal-project](https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project), and include a dependency on `drush/drush`.  I also put

```
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin/"
},
```

in my composer.json.  Then I use [direnv](https://direnv.net/) to set up a path for the root directory in drupal project.  My .envrc will contain a line like

```
PATH_add /var/www/prod/bin
```

This prepends $PATH with this directory, so this version of drush will be picked up for that project.  This ensures that drush is pulling the same dependencies as that particular drupal install.